# What is the precedence of the ! operator vs -- in the expression !x--?

Tags: c++, logical-operators

This particular code

```
if (!x--)
```

where `x` is an `int` and `!` is the NOT operator.

What does this code do and why?

Comment: `--` has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). What you have is equivalent to `! (si--)`

Comment: i would read up on the operators involved here.

Comment: any integer that is not zero is `true`, and zero is the only `int` that is `false`. The expression you mentioned, decrements `si` by one, and if it was zero before decrement returns `true`, otherwise returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks triple_r, very clear :)

Comment: I think that this question, and the answers, are very clear. No idea why people downvoted and put it on hold.

Comment: While his English was pretty poor the question seems very obvious even in the original posting.

Comment: @anatolyg definitely clear enough, but it shows a lack of research. Downvoting seems reasonable.

Comment: I think this code is not very well readable and I would probably never write it this way. But for understanding code of others this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

There are two operators here, the first is the post-decrement operator `--` which means reduce `x` by 1 and return the original value.

The second is the `!` operator which is the logical NOT operator, which returns `true` if its operand is zero, and `false` if it is not zero.

`--` has higher precedence so it will be evaluated first.

Thus the code reduces `x` by 1, and then executes the body of the conditional if `x` was 0 before the line was reached.

Comment: Just because `--` has higher precedence doesn't mean it will be done first.  With post-increment and post-decrement, the current value is returned and then the increment or decrement happens later.  The higher precedence just means the decrement won't be applied to the result of `!si`, which wouldn't make any sense anyway, that result not being an lvalue.

Comment: When I say done first I mean that the expression will be evaluated as `!(x--)` rather than `(!x)--`.

Comment: @JackAidley that's actually not correct, because `x--` returns the actual value of `x`, *not `x-1`*, which is then evaluated by the `!` operator. Or am I wrong? EDIT: `(!x)--` would of course be wrong because decrementing a boolean... my bad. But I feel like your answer is unclear about the value that gets evaluated by the `!`...

Comment: @Theolodis: I thought I made that clear both when I said "return the original value" and when I say "was 0 before the line was reached". What else do you feel I need to say to make this point clear?

Comment: I think it's just the ambiguity of the word "done" - the rest of your answer is clear.  Evaluated first, but decremented later.

Comment: @Gordon: The decrement can happen at any time. It's the value used that in the expression that is the value prior to the decrement. It's a mistake, in my view, to think that the decrement is delayed; that isn't what happens. `x--` is equivalent to function `int decX(int& x) { int t = x; x -= 1; return t; }` except the compiler is allowed to play first and lose with execution order of that `x-=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "--" is used as a postfix operator, it decrements the variable 'x' only after 'x'' is evaluated.

If `x` was zero before, then the true part of the if statement will be executed.

`x` will be decremented regardless of whether it was zero or not.

Comment: @Trilarion No, they both explain that it decrements `si`, and if  it was 0 before the statement, the body will be executed.

Comment: @NobodyNada You're right. It was too late yesterday but now I see it clearly. Just two way of explaining the same thing and both very nicely done. :)